# MS-Office 2010 Professional Plus - Change Product Key error

Tags: microsoft-office-2010, product-key, software-activation

I installed MS-Office 2010 Professional Plus 1 month ago. But now it is giving error when I open any of its product like Outlook, Word, Excel etc.

[image]

Please help me what can I do for that? I do not have product key. What should I enter in Change Product Key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Office is highly cost software.. you have installed it on your computer as like windows operating system this needs an `product key` printed on the pack of the software CD/DVD.

If you have genuine Microsoft product then you should enter the product key that they have provided you and if it have any issue then go to Microsoft office support [website](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/support/)..

follow this [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/support/results.aspx?filter=1&ck=1&qu=Activate%202010) for more information  and check this [Activate Office 2010 programs](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-workspace-help/activate-office-2010-programs-HA010354227.aspx?CTT=1) to know about activation process

Answer (score 7):

You need to pay for it to keep using it... It's not freeware

Comment: hmm .. but I have the paid version.

Comment: Your receipt should of came with a copy of the product key. Or your reseller should of gave you a copy of the product key.